# Violin plot of ggplot2 requires an x variable even though there is none

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a violin plot with the continuous variable *tm_aerobic_vario* which has the following values:

```
NA  50 614  30  60 180 120 240  12  60 135 120  25 120 120  60  10 120  90
90  30   0 180 120  30   5   0   0  60 180 120  24  30  30  40  40   0 180
60 180  45   0  10  30 120 120   1  45  15  30 180
```

The code is:

```
ggplot(initdata, aes(x = 1, y = tm_aerobic_vario)) + 
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE,fill="gray") + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1) + 
  theme_apa()
```

It keeps insisting that it needs an x value (in another dataset, I used x as 'Group' and it made a nice graph with two groups in the x axis) although there is no x value for me to provide. Thus the graph below

[image]

What can I do to replace the X axis, or which value is the correct to provide in case of only 1 variable?

Comment: The x-value should be a categorical variable. You can just create a dataframe where `tm_aerobic_vario` is one column, and the other column contains the same character variable (e.g. "Group") in every row.

Comment: I see! so I can leave it blank such as ```x = ""```. Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add it as an complete example below. You can edit the axis even more if you want to get rid of it completely.

```
library(ggplot2)

initdata <- data.frame(tm_aerobic_vario = c(NA, 50, 614, 30, 60, 180, 120, 240, 
                       12, 60, 135, 120, 25, 120, 120, 60, 10, 120, 90, 90, 30, 
                     0, 180, 120, 30, 5, 0, 0, 60, 180, 120, 24, 30, 30, 40, 40, 
                     0, 180, 60, 180, 45, 0, 10, 30, 120, 120, 1, 45, 15, 30, 180))

ggplot(initdata, aes(x = "tm aerobic vario", y=tm_aerobic_vario)) +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  geom_violin(trim = F, fill = "gray") + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1) +
  theme_classic() +
  # theme(axis.text = element_blank(), 
  #       axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) # to get rid of axis completely
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As neilfws wrote, x is a factor, so you can just leave it blank by writing `x = ""`

```
ggplot(initdata, aes(x = "", y = tm_aerobic_vario)) + 
  geom_violin(trim=FALSE,fill="gray") + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1) + 
  theme_apa()
```